# ftp_nlist "Resource temporarily unavailable (11)"

Tags: php

Issue: you connect with php `ftp_nlist` and you get "`resource temporarily unavailable`". As a result there is no contents listings and your php ftp script will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: the server was using 2 IP addresses (one I connect to and one going to out bound connections). Checked in filezilla server (which we were running) and could see the connection but not from the IP I expected. So check your outbound ip config is correct and that firewall rules are setup on the server to allow that IP rather than the one you may think.